# How to fix Xcode 7.3 warning: `init` is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3: Use `enumerate()` method on the sequence

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode7.3, swift3

From recent update of Xcode 7.3, I started seeing this message. I am using a sequence for in loop as below:

```
for (index, product) in EnumerateSequence(self.products) {
     //Do something with the product

     //Do something with the index
}
```

The note is on the `EnumerateSequence`.

Comment: You haven't stated an actual question here, and the warning message itself (which you quoted in your title) tells you how to eliminate the warning message. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're wondering **why** they added this warning and are going to remove `EnumerateSequence.init`, it's because `EnumerateSequence` is an implementation detail of the `enumerate` method. They want you to use `enumerate` and not rely on how it's implemented.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, this is the solution to use from Swift 2.2 onwards in case you want to use both the `index` and the `object`:

```
for (index, product) in self.products.enumerate() {
    //Do something with the product

    //Do something with the index
}
```

Remove `EnumerateSequence` and use your `Array.enumerate()` method

Comment: This is the first time the answer to the question is already in the question title.

Comment: In your case you want to use `for index in self.products.indices`, no need for `enumerate` if you don't want to use the item.

Comment: I made the question more clear, let's assume we need both the index and the object.

Comment: @Sulthan OP is also providing his own answer. Also, this has nothing to do with Swift 2.2, enumerate() was there since Swift 2.0.